# My discord counting bot is Not doing server by server but every single server combined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need help with a discord counting bot. Whatever server it is in, it has the same counter number. what I mean is that they are all paired and do the same count instead of it being server by server.

Here is the main part (not all of it), I just need to learn to have the servers separate from one another:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

var counter = [{
name: "bot",
nummer: 0  
}];
client.on("message", message => {
if (message.channel.name === "counting") {
    if (!isNaN(message.content)){
        var counterlast = counter[counter.length - 1];
        var countercheck = counterlast["nummer"] + 1;
        var pinger = parseInt(message.content);
        var lastuser = counterlast["name"];
        if(countercheck === pinger && lastuser !== message.author.id){
            counter.push({name: message.author.id, nummer: countercheck});
            message.react('✅');
        }
        else{
            if(lastuser === message.author.id){
                message.react('❌');
                message.reply(`Wrong Number. The new number is **1**.`);
                counter.length = 0;
                counter.push({name: "bot", nummer: 0}); Number
            }
            else{
                message.react('❌');
                message.reply(` ruined it at ${countercheck}. the new 
                number is **1**.`);
                counter.length = 0;
                counter.push({name: "bot", nummer: 0});
             }
         }
     }
  }
 });

  client.login('N/A');
```

Comment: How does your counter's code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this counting bot is or how you store your data. However, you can get the server id from the message by accessing `message.guild.id`. It means that you can check this id before you do anything to the server's "count".

You can use an object with the server ids as its keys like this:

```js
const counter = {
  `630930214659670528`: 304,
  `630136153655430054`: 941,
  `685932343451250658`: 34123,
};
```

The following code increases the counter of the server it's accessed from by one:

```js
const counter = {};

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.channel.name === 'counting' || isNaN(message.content)) return;

  // get the server id
  const { id } = message.guild;
  counter[id] = counter[id] ? counter[id] + 1 : 1;

  message.channel.send(`The counter is at ${counter[id]}`);
});
```

**Edit:** As you've updated your question with your code, here's how I'd add different counters for different servers:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();
const counters = {};

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (
    message.author.bot ||
    message.channel.name !== 'counting' ||
    isNaN(message.content)
  )
    return;

  const { id } = message.guild;

  // if this is the first counter from this server set it up
  if (!counters[id]) {
    counters[id] = [
      {
        name: 'bot',
        value: 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  const counter = counters[id];
  const last = counter[counter.length - 1];
  const increasedValue = last.value + 1;
  const pingerCount = parseInt(message.content);

  if (increasedValue === pingerCount && last.name !== message.author.id) {
    counter.push({ name: message.author.id, value: increasedValue });
    message.react('✅');
  } else {
    if (last.name === message.author.id) {
      message.react('❌');
      message.reply(
        'Wrong, the last user was also you. The new number is **1**.',
      );
      counter.length = 0;
      counter.push({ name: 'bot', value: 0 });
    } else {
      message.react('❌');
      message.reply(`Ruined it at ${increasedValue}, the new number is **1**.`);
      counter.length = 0;
      counter.push({ name: 'bot', value: 0 });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I just updated my post to show you what I have so far

Comment: Yes! thank you for the help. By chance, do you know how to add a JASON file to save numbers in a server. Sometimes I have to restart the bot restarting the counting in the server. DO you know how I could add a JSON file to save the numbers they left off at?